# simulating a 6 DOF robot in matlab robotic toolbox

Tags: matlab, robotics

I am new with matlab and its robotic toolbox. I am trying to simulate a simple model of a 6 DOF manipulator in matlab but i got this error. Here is my code:

```
clc

startup_rvc;  
syms th1 th2 th3 th4 th5 
%//////////robot  d-h////////////
%%%%L= Link([ th d a alpha 'joint type'])%%%%
L(1) = Link([th1 0.1519 0 -pi/2 ]);
L(2) = Link([th2 0.1198 0.24365 0 ]);
L(3) = Link([th3 -0.0925 0.21325 0 ]);
L(4) = Link([th4 0.08505 0 -pi/2 ]);
L(5)= Link([th5 0.08535 0 pi/2]);
L(6)= Link([th6 0 0 0]);

robot = SerialLink(L,'name','surgicalarm');
q=[0 0 0 0 0];
robot.plot(q)
robot.teach();
```

but when I run this code I got this error:

```
Error using SerialLink/plot (line 205)
Insufficient columns in q

Error in surgicalarm (line 16)
robot.plot(q)
```

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since your robot has 6 DOF, I would expect `q` also have 6 columns instead of 5.

Try with `q = [0 0 0 0 0 0]` in your code.